# exception str() failed - py3

Tags: python, python-3.x

This works fine in Py2 but fails in Py3

```
import sys

class MyBaseError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message, base_message=None, *args):
        
        self.base_message = base_message
        super(MyBaseError, self).__init__(message)
        
        
    def __str__(self):
        if self.base_message is None:
            return self.message
        
        return self.message + " '" + str(self.base_message) + "'"
        
        
class MyError(MyBaseError):
    """
    """
    
class MyTypeError(MyError):
    """
    """

def run_me():
    raise MyTypeError("run_me")
    

def sayonara():
    try:
        run_me()
    except (MyBaseError) as e:
        raise(MyBaseError("unable to run",
                           e,
                           e.args),
                sys.exc_info()[2])
                
sayonara()
```

In Py2 I am getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 39, in <module>
    sayonara()
  File "main.py", line 37, in sayonara
    sys.exc_info()[2])
__main__.MyBaseError: unable to run 'run_me'
```

In Py3 I am getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 32, in sayonara
    run_me()
  File "main.py", line 27, in run_me
    raise MyTypeError("run_me")
__main__.MyTypeError: <exception str() failed>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 42, in <module>
    sayonara()
  File "main.py", line 34, in sayonara
    print(e)
  File "main.py", line 13, in __str__
    return self.message
AttributeError: 'MyTypeError' object has no attribute 'message'
```

Can you suggest how can I make this polyglot?

Comment: Have you tried `class MyBaseError(BaseException)`

Comment: You also never set a `self.message`

Comment: message is passed to  super

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62520780/exceptions-must-derive-from-baseexception-py3

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? I tested your code with Python 3.8.0b1 and got a different traceback.

Comment: Also, this code still has the error for which you already got an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62524067/10669875)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your overridden implementation of the `__str__` instance method that you define in MyBaseError references the **instance variable** `message` that does not exist. The parameter `message` declared in the signature of your constructor has a **local scope**.

When you pass immutable arguments like strings to a function, the value of the argument is passed. In the constructor of `MyBaseError` you pass the value of the local variable `message` to the `__init__` method of the proxy object that delegates method calls to the parent class `Exception`.

In python3, `Exception` does not define an instance variable `message` that holds the string representation of the arguments to an instance. This is what causes the exceptions.

Furthermore, if you resolve that issue you will get a Type error:

```
TypeError: exceptions must derive from BaseException
```

That's because the raise statement you wrote does not conform to the semantics of a raise statement in Python 3. The BNF for the raise statement is shown below:

```
raise_stmt ::=  "raise" [expression ["from" expression]]
```

As stated by the language reference: 'raise evaluates the first expression as the exception object. It must either be a subclass or an instance of BaseException.'

However, in your raise statement the first expression is a tuple:

```
(MyBaseError("unable to run", e, e.args), sys.exc_info()[2])
```

(https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-raise-statement).

To fix your code, make `message` an instance variable and refactor the raise statement.

```py
import sys


class MyBaseError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message, base_message=None, *args):
        self.base_message = base_message
        self.message = message

    def __str__(self):
        if self.base_message is None:
            return self.message

        return self.message + " '" + str(self.base_message) + "'"


class MyError(MyBaseError):
    """
    """


class MyTypeError(MyError):
    """
    """


def run_me():
    raise MyTypeError("run_me")


def sayonara():
    try:
        run_me()
    except (MyBaseError) as e:
        raise MyBaseError("unable to run", e, e.args)


sayonara()
```

Additionally the statement below, from your code, returns a traceback object.

```
sys.exc_info()[2]
```

As stated by the language reference: 'A traceback object is normally created **automatically** when an exception is raised and attached to it as the **traceback** attribute, which is writable.' Should you wish to, you can set your own custom traceback in one step using the with_traceback() exception method.