# Exceptions must derive from BaseException

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

What am I missing here?

```
import sys

class MyBaseError(BaseException):
    def __init__(self, message, base_message=None, *args):
        
        self.message = message
        self.base_message = base_message
        super(MyBaseError, self).__init__()
        
        
    def __str__(self):
        if self.base_message is None:
            return self.message
        
        return self.message + " '" + str(self.base_message) + "'"
        
        
class MyError(MyBaseError):
    """
    """
    
class MyTypeError(MyError):
    """
    """

def run_me():
    raise MyTypeError("run_me")
    

def sayonara():
    try:
        run_me()
    except (MyBaseError) as e:
        raise(MyBaseError("unable to run",
                           e,
                           e.args),
                sys.exc_info()[2])
        
sayonara()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 32, in sayonara
    run_me()
  File "main.py", line 27, in run_me
    raise MyTypeError("run_me")
__main__.MyTypeError: run_me

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 42, in <module>
    sayonara()
  File "main.py", line 40, in sayonara
    sys.exc_info()[2])
TypeError: exceptions must derive from BaseException
```

MyBaseError class is already deriving from BaseException.

Comment: According to the Python 3 [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html) "_programmers are encouraged to derive new exceptions from the Exception class or one of its subclasses, and not from BaseException._"

Answer (score 3):

In your `sayonara()` function, it seems you are attempting to raise a tuple of exceptions. The problem is that `sys.exc_info()[2]` is a traceback, and not an exception, which is the cause of your break. I verified this by placing the following line at the top of the exception block:

```
print(type(sys.exc_info()[2]))
```

I'm not certain of what you are trying to do for sure, but a working version of `sayonara()` is as follows:

```
def sayonara():
    try:
        run_me()
    except (MyBaseError) as e:
        raise MyBaseError("unable to run", e, e.args)
```

If you want to include the traceback, you'll need to update your custom Error classes to handle that argument being passed through.

Answer (score 2):

That means you should raise the Exception class or an instance of it.
For example

```py
try:
   1 + "String"
except TypeError:
   raise TypeError("unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'")
```